# Stripe Connect is functional with Old Stripe api versions?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

Dose 'Stripe connect' is functional with Stripe API version 1.18.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.18.0 of the [Stripe PHP bindings](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php#stripe-php-bindings) will be able to use some Connect features, but not all.

Most importantly, you will not be able to use [`Stripe-Account`](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#authentication-via-the-stripe-account-header) header, which is the recommended way of issuing API requests on behalf of another account.

I would recommend using the latest version of the PHP bindings. Note that the syntax changed in version 2.0.0: all `Stripe_Class` class names are now `\Stripe\Class`.

All the examples in Stripe's [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs) and [API reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api) use the syntax for the latest version.

Comment: this is soo good . i'm working on CakePHP project , i did configure stripe using [chronon stripe](https://github.com/chronon/CakePHP-StripeComponent-Plugin) this . but this is old version .
what changes i have to make to shift this to new version .

p.s cant give you marks , im very new here ,

Comment: last comment is for you